# File used by another process - StreamWriter

Tags: c#, asynchronous, streamwriter

I have checked all other solutions, nothing is working.
I am calling an asynchronous logging method from different button events.

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(() => LoggerTest());
}

private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(() => LoggerTest());
}

private async void LoggerTest()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        Logger.Log(string.Format("Counter: {0}", i));
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    }
}
```

Log method uses **StreamWriter**

```
private void Log(string log)
{
    if (!IsFileLocked(fullPath))
    {
        using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(fullPath, append: true))
        {
            file.WriteLine(log);
            file.Close(); // I know this is unnecessary in the using block
        }
    }
}

private bool IsFileLocked(string file)
{
    try
    {
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(file))
            return false;
    }
    catch (IOException)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

When I click on button1 and button2, the below exception is caught:

> **System.IO.IOException**: 'The process cannot access the file 'C:..\x.txt' because it is being used by another process.'

Comment: The check `IsFileLocked` is useless given the parallelism of the operations. It can `return false;` and be immediately locked by the other Task running

Comment: It is a classic threading race bug.  Use the lock keyword to ensure only one thread can access the file at the same time.  Not a good logging strategy btw, this is far too expensive.  Look at NLog, etc.

Comment: Don't try to reinvent the wheel, use one of the available logging libraries like NLog, Serilog or Microsoft.Extensions.Logging. In this particular case you're trying to write to the same file from multiple threads. A file can only have *one* writer at a time though. That's a multipe publishers/single subscriber problem. To fix this you need to post any messages to some kind od concurrent queue and have just *one* subscriber on the other side read messages and write them out.

Comment: You can use a ConcurrentQueue, ActionBlock<T>,  or a System.Threading.Channels.Channel to implement the pub/sub operation. `Log` should just post to the queue, nothing more. Writing the text will be a job for the subscriber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

```
 private static readonly object locker = new object();
lock (locker)
            {
                using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("FilePath"), FileMode.Append))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
                    {
                        writer.WriteLine(log);
                    }
                }
            }
```

lock keyword will lock the stream writer till the current writer process is finished

Comment: Thanks that was helpful